# Usage of bash return code and concurrency

Tags: bash

Is this code snippet safe (concurrency calls / usage of `$?` / ...)?

```
#/bin/bash

call-to-custum-script.sh
exit $?
```

The question is about the `exit $?`.

Because I have encountered a bug (when a lot of concurrent calls of this script are done). And during debug, I have probably resolved the problem with the following change (added result variable to display the result in log):

```
#/bin/bash

call-to-custum-script.sh
result=$?
exit ${result}
```

So I suppose the problem is related to the `$?` as I cannot reproduce the bug (only appears on production server), I want to know if I missed something about the $?.

Comment: You usage is ok. `when a lot of concurrent calls are done` - are the concurrent calls inside this script or inside `call-to-custom-script.sh` script? Maybe `call-to-custom-script.sh` does not return what you think it does. Your fix looks like fixing a heisenbug.

Comment: Thank you, you probably right. I have add this return code value to log the result exit code, and now I can't get a new occurence of the bug... I will continue my monitoring

Comment: Where is the concurrency in your example?

Comment: The concurrency is outside the script. Does this script is thread-safe

Comment: Please read this [mcve]. Complete and Verifiable is important to understand the problem.

Comment: I understand your point... But I really think, you have misread the question. Who is : "Does I miss something about the usage of $?" (note : Kamil Cuk has answered the question). I fully follow the guide (I just can't reproduce the problem but that's the point)...

Comment: There's no bug in the original script, no matter what kind of concurrent processing is going on. I'm guessing that either 1. The original script was something like `call-to-custum-script.sh; echo "Exiting with $?"; exit $?` which would indeed botch the exit code, or 2. Whatever tracked the exit code had a bug, since there are many ways of accidentally squashing exit values

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
#/bin/bash
exec call-to-custum-script.sh
```

This will do the same and will use fewer resources.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a code snippet, in the real script we are inside a "if" and we want to stop the execution.

Comment: Then update your example. The example is somehow useles if it does not show your requirement.

Comment: I understand your point... But I keep in simple the question, does my code is safe. Your response is fine, but do not answer the question -> does my code is safe with a correct usage of exit $?

Comment: Using the variable directly or copying the variable into another variable and using the other variable does not make any difference for the script. But if you have a timing problem somewhere else, it might make a difference for the other code, because copying a variable needs some time.